# Jquery.get only returns 1

Tags: jquery

So, i have this script what is supposed to retrive a value from a .txt file, that gets updated every 10 seconds. However, the .txt changes every 10 second, according to the plan, but the website only displays 1 as the value i needed to load.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>RNJESUS</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="rnjesus.ico">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    </head>

    <body background="rnjesus.jpg" style="background-size: 100%" text="white">
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <p align="center"> Üdvözlégy a félkész szerencsejáték szimulátorban. <br>
                    4 dologra lehet fogadni: 50 alatt, felett és ezen belül páros vagy páratlan.<br>
                    A Random Number Geisus (RNJézus) kisorsol neked egy számot 0 és 100 között. <br>
                    10 vagy az alatt, 90 vagy a felett, és kereken 50-nél a "ház" nyer. <br>
                    Jó játékot, és ne felejtkezz el imátkozzni RNJesushoz.<br>
    </p>

    <p align="center">
        Mennyivel akarsz beszállni?<br>
        <input type="number" min="1" name="fogcredit">
        <button onclick="otvenalatt()">Fogadás: 50 alatt.</button>
        <button onclick="otvenfelett()">Fogadás: 50 felett.</button>
        <button id="start" onclick="bevitel()"> My body is ready </button>
    </p>
    <h1 align="center" id="warning"></h1>
    <div align="center" id="creditcount"></div>
    <div align="center" id="timer"></div>
    <div align="center" id="szam"></div>
    <div align="center" id="otven"></div>
    <div align="center" id="paratlan"></div>
    <h2 align="center" id="nyeremeny" ></h2>


    <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
    <script>
    //<![CDATA[
        var frn
        var otvenvar;
        var nyeremenycredit;
        var credit = 100
        var otvenvar
        var fogbevitel
        var fogadas
        var nyeremenycredit
        var credit
        var ido = 10


        jQuery.get("szamok.txt", function(data){
            frn = data;
        });



        function bevitel(){
        fogadas = document.getElementsByName("fogcredit")[0].value;
        }

        document.getElementById("creditcount").innerHTML = ("Jelenlegi krediteid:" + credit);
        function otvenfelett(){
        otvenvar = 1;
        }
        function otvenalatt(){
        otvenvar = 0;

        }
        setInterval(function jesus(){
            if (credit > fogadas || credit == fogadas){
                document.getElementById('szam').innerHTML = ("Szám: " +frn);
                credit = credit - fogadas;
                nyeremenycredit = 0
                document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML = ("");

                if (frn < 11){
                    document.getElementById('otven').innerHTML = ('The house always wins.');
                    document.getElementById('paratlan').innerHTML = ("Mivel a ház nyert, nem számít hogy páros vagy pártalan.");
                    document.getElementById("creditcount").innerHTML = ("Jelenlegi krediteid:" + credit);
                    fogadas = 0
                }

                if (frn > 89){
                    document.getElementById('otven').innerHTML = ("The house always wins.");
                    document.getElementById('paratlan').innerHTML = ("Mivel a ház nyert, nem számít hogy páros vagy pártalan.");
                    document.getElementById("creditcount").innerHTML = ("Jelenlegi krediteid:" + credit);
                    fogadas = 0
                }

                if (frn == 50){
                    document.getElementById('otven').innerHTML = ("The house always wins.");
                    document.getElementById('paratlan').innerHTML = ("Mivel a ház nyert, nem számít hogy páros vagy pártalan.");
                    document.getElementById("creditcount").innerHTML = ("Jelenlegi krediteid:" + credit);
                    fogadas = 0
                }

                if (frn > 10 && frn < 50){
                    document.getElementById('otven').innerHTML = ("50 alatt nyert.");
                    document.getElementById("creditcount").innerHTML = ("Jelenlegi krediteid:" + credit);

                    if (otvenvar == 0){
                        nyeremenycredit = fogadas * 2;
                        credit = credit + nyeremenycredit;

                        document.getElementById("creditcount").innerHTML = ("Jelenlegi krediteid:" + credit);
                    }

                    if (frn % 2 == 0){
                        document.getElementById('paratlan').innerHTML = ('Páros szám nyert.');
                        document.getElementById("creditcount").innerHTML = ("Jelenlegi krediteid:" + credit);
                        fogadas = 0
                    }

                    else{
                        document.getElementById('paratlan').innerHTML = ('Páratlan szám nyert.');
                        document.getElementById("creditcount").innerHTML = ("Jelenlegi krediteid:" + credit);
                        fogadas = 0
                    }

                }

                if (frn < 90 && frn > 50){
                    document.getElementById('otven').innerHTML = ("50 felett nyert.");
                    if (otvenvar == 1){
                        nyeremenycredit = fogadas * 2;
                        credit = credit + nyeremenycredit;

                        document.getElementById("creditcount").innerHTML = ("Jelenlegi krediteid:" + credit);
                    }

                    if (frn % 2 == 0){
                        document.getElementById('paratlan').innerHTML = ("Páros szám nyert.");
                        document.getElementById("creditcount").innerHTML = ("Jelenlegi krediteid:" + credit);
                        fogadas = 0
                    }

                    else{
                        document.getElementById('paratlan').innerHTML = ("Páratlan szám nyert.");
                        document.getElementById("creditcount").innerHTML = ("Jelenlegi krediteid:" + credit);
                        fogadas = 0
                    }

                }
            }

            jQuery.get("szamok.txt", function(data){
                frn = data
            })

            if (credit < fogadas){
            document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML = ("Nincs elég credit!");
            }
        }, 10000);

        setInterval(function(){
            if (ido > 0){
                ido = ido - 1;
                document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = ("Ennyi idő van hátra:" + ido);
            }
            if (ido === 0){
                document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = ("Sorsolás megtörtént.");
                ido = 10;
            }
        }, 1000);   
    //]]>
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The whole code is above.
I got no errors in the console.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's because a browser caches HTTP-request and doesn't make a GET-request to the same URL. Try make like this:

```
jQuery.get("szamok.txt?v=" + Math.random(), function(data){
    frn = data
});
```

Comment: Best increment a counter instead of using `Math.random()` since you run the risk of calling from the same version value as a previous request.

Comment: Thank you very much! I Don't realy understand what that math random is doing there, when it should be server sided in a seperate script, but suprisingly, it works! Could you explain please what does it do there?

Comment: @CsabaKiss: Browser caches are by URL, so changing the URL randomly stops cached responses from being reused. Your server should send a `Cache-Control` with a low `max-age` or `no-cache` instead, though.

Comment: @Prusprus: Until you refresh the containing page =)